# Refrer javascript inside html file?

Tags: javascript, ajax, html

I have below folder structure.

inside: `webapp/WEB-INF/some.jsp`  i have

i have javascript file in the same `webapp/WEB-INF/js/myform.js` location

i referred it in some.jsp as below:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/myform.js"></script>
```

But it is not finding javascript file. in viewsource i am getting below lines:

```
<title>Error 404 NOT_FOUND</title>
</head>
<body><h2>HTTP ERROR: 404</h2><pre>NOT_FOUND</pre>
<p>RequestURI=/js/myform.js</p><p><i><small><a href="http://jetty.mortbay.org/">Powered by Jetty://</a></small></i></p><br/>
```

is my javascript link correct in jsp file?

Please correct me.

Thanks!

Comment: I guess static assets like css, images, js files should be placed in some other location.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. i placed js folder directly under webapp folder. now how can i refer it in jsp?

Answer (score 1):

The `WEB-INF` folder is secure, meaning you can't access resources placed in it directly using a URL from the browser.

To work around it, place the JS under the `webapp/js` directory.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. if i keep my js in webapp then how can i refer it in some.jsp?

Comment: Just as you're doing it now. In `<script type="text/javascript" src="js/myform.js"></script>`, the `js` is relative to the webapp.

Answer (score 0):

webapp/WEB-INF is not the root of your application, put your dir **js** in **webapp** rather than in **webapp/WEB-INF**

Comment: Thanks for your reply. if i keep my js in webapp then how can i refer it in some.jsp?

Comment: It depends on the URL you use to access the content of your JSP rather than its final location (for sure your URL doesn't include /WEB-INF/some.jsp, is it?) if, for instance, your URL is __http: //localhost/one/two/myPage.do__ and your javascript is at _[ROOT]_ __/js/myForm.js__, then your script tag must be like <script type="text/javascript" src="../../js/myform.js"></script>